# GLSL endianness macro

Tags: opengl, glsl, endianness

Is there any way to check endianness of target machine inside GLSL? For example in OpenCL I could use

```
#ifdef __ENDIAN_LITTLE__
uint x = v << 1;
#else
uint x = v >> 1;
#endif
```

Comment: You could check on the CPU side and pass it as a uniform. It's not something you need to pass every frame, once is enough, before the render loop even begins.

Comment: By target machine do you mean GPU? Is there even a case when it affects any outcome? If you supply your `v` as a uniform or a vertex attribute, presumably only the endianness of the CPU plays a role, and even there, if it's a `GL...` type like `GLuint`, it's supposed to pass the value as expected.

Comment: Yes, I meant GPU. And yes, it can make a difference. For example I'm trying to pass a byte buffer to GLSL but of course there is no byte data-type and depending on endianess, my `char * cpu_data` will be mapped to `uint * glsl_data` in different ways. I need to know whether that uint is of the form `0xZ000` or `0x000Z` (where Z is the original value of `char`).

Comment: @AndreiDespinoiu I thought about it too, but I cannot find any function that would allow me to query endianness of GPU.

Comment: The endinanness of the GPU in OpenGL matches the endinaness of the host; passing data via buffer objects would be hell otherwise.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Maybe I'm missing something but that doesn't seem to make any sense to me. The endianness of GPU is a feature of its architecture. I can literally take my gpu out of my PC and put it in another host with a different endianness but the endianness of the GPU won't magically change just because it's connected to a different CPU. And besides, OpenCL allows me to check endianness, so why wouldn't OpenGL too.

Comment: @alagris Can you really though? Pretty much every consumer GPU is either connected via PCIe to an x86 processor (which all use little endian), integrated into the CPU (embedded graphics), or part of the PCB hardware (embedded).

Comment: You can use [bitfieldInsert()](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#integer-functions) instead of shift-operator. Endianness is not needed to use this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching for "endian" in the GLSL 4.60 specification doesn't yield any match. A search for "order" only reveals irrelevant results. So I suppose there's no special way to query endianness of the GPU in GLSL.

Your best bet is to detect it with a specially-crafted shader once at the beginning (like, read the supplied byte buffer as a uint and put an endianness-dependent result in the output fragment, then `glReadPixels`), and then, based on the result, just insert the appropriate `#define`s into the shaders that depend on this.